# JsonIgnore using Open API spec

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I use [OpenAPI](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification) spec to generate Java POJOs. What do I need to specify in Open API yaml to generate the equivalent of below POJO ?

```
...
@JsonIgnore
public String ignoredProperty;
...
```

I have the yaml spec as below

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Cool API
  description: A Cool API spec
  version: 0.0.1
servers:
  - url: http://api.cool.com/v1
    description: Cool server for testing
paths:
  /
  ...
components:
  schemas:
    MyPojo:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
        name:
          type: string
        # I want the below attribute to be ignored as a part of JSON 
        ignoreProperty:  
          type: string
```

Comment: @Fazal before adding tags please review the tag wiki. [tag:api] excerpt clearly says : DO NOT USE

Comment: thank you for clarifying my misunderstanding @Ruben Sir

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `openapi generator` supports vendor extensions.  Specifically, for the Java generator, it supports the following extensions as of the time of writing.  However, an up-to-date list can be found [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/java.md#supported-vendor-extensions).

| Extension name | Description | Applicable for | Default value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x-discriminator-value | Used with model inheritance to specify value for discriminator that identifies current model | MODEL |  |
| x-implements | Ability to specify interfaces that model must implements | MODEL | empty array |
| x-setter-extra-annotation | Custom annotation that can be specified over java setter for specific field | FIELD | When field is array & uniqueItems, then this extension is used to add `@JsonDeserialize(as = LinkedHashSet.class)` over setter, otherwise no value |
| x-tags | Specify multiple swagger tags for operation | OPERATION | null |
| x-accepts | Specify custom value for 'Accept' header for operation | OPERATION | null |
| x-content-type | Specify custom value for 'Content-Type' header for operation | OPERATION | null |
| x-class-extra-annotation | List of custom annotations to be added to model | MODEL | null |
| x-field-extra-annotation | List of custom annotations to be added to property | FIELD | null |
| x-webclient-blocking | Specifies if method for specific operation should be blocking or non-blocking(ex: return `Mono<T>/Flux<T>` or `return T/List<T>/Set<T>` & execute `.block()` inside generated method) | OPERATION | false |

You can use the `x-field-extra-annotation` vendor extension listed above to add annotations to any field.  So, for your example, you can add the following:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Cool API
  description: A Cool API spec
  version: 0.0.1
servers:
  - url: http://api.cool.com/v1
    description: Cool server for testing
paths:
  /
  ...
components:
  schemas:
    MyPojo:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
        name:
          type: string
        # I want the below attribute to be ignored as a part of JSON 
        ignoreProperty:  
          type: string  
          x-field-extra-annotation: "@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore"
```

Comment: How to add property to the annotation? Like- @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)